# Time complexity of log(n+logn)

Tags: time-complexity

Is time complexity of log(n+logn) is equal to theta log(n)?
Can I take only the dominants from inside of a log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

$$\log(n)\le\log(n+\log n)=\log n+\log\left(1+\frac{\log n}n\right)\le\log n+\log(1+e^{-1}).$$

---

More generally,

$$\log(f(n))\le\log(f(n)+g(n))=\log(f(n))+\log\left(1+\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\right)\le \log(f(n))+\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$$ and if the last term is $o(1)$ you can drop it.